# PHP ob_get_clean within WHILE loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I have looked extensively on this question and have yet to come across an answer, so forgive me if this has already been answered.

In a nutshell,

```
while ($prod_row = mysql_fetch_array($query_prod)){

ob_start();
```

at the start of a while loop and

```
$html = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents("$sku_pass.php", $html);
}
```

at the end.  The expected result is to create a .php file for every entry in the database, but of course it only returns the first record and creates the file but the while loop is then broken.

What is a better way to do this.

BTW I know mysql_fetch_array is deprecated, that is not my problem at the moment, so please decline to comment on that one aspect.

UPDATE*****
It IS.......  it is impossible!  Script runs without errors, so no, there is not a problem with the rest of the script (otherwise NONE of the website would function as it is the exact same coding).  No examples exist of running ob_get_clean within a while loop, and for my purpose there is no alternative.  Thanks Anyway! :)

Comment: What is your output? Can't you just put it in a string?

Comment: Nope, it is not just a string but an entire page.  Wait, that would prolly work, but whats the function to load from point a to point b into a string?

Comment: I suppose `$sku_pass` changes every loop, am I correct? Show your code.

Comment: It is too long to post all of it, and is sensitive.  All code between the snippets that I posted is php/javascript/html that is generated from database entries, and yes, $sku_pass is going to be different every iteration.

Comment: Well there is nothing wrong with this piece of code. The problem is somewhere else you are not showing us.

Comment: The real question is what is an alternative to buffering output in order to collect everything within the loop and save it to an individual file.

Comment: Well, instead of printing it just append it to a string or write it directly to the file with `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()`.

Comment: Havenard, I know there is nothing wrong per say, however the ob_get_clean seems to break the while loop.  there is nothing in the rest of the code that could break it as the PHP file that IS created is perfect, so it is not failing somewhere else to break the loop, at least...I think.

Comment: As far as fopen etc..  The how would I mimic what ob_start() and ob_get_clean() do with file functions only?

Comment: It can be many things. The script may have permission to overwrite the existing file, but not to create new ones. Perhaps its overwriting the same file giving the impression that its generating only one. Perhaps you are running out of memory. Perhaps you are overwriting the variable `$query_prod`, I don't know. If you want us to help you will need to provide some code.

Comment: `ob_start()` basically creates a output buffer that will catch everything you print with `echo`, `print`, `printf`, `print_r` and similars. Those functions write directly to the output and there is no other way to catch them if not creating output buffers. Howover, you don't have to use them. Write to a file with `fwrite`, `fprintf` etc.

Comment: ok, I cannot post the code, as I said it is for a large corporation, but like I said, all the code between what I show is the same as if you were looking at a webpage made from html, php, and jquery, that is not the issue I promise, ob_get_clean BREAKS THE WHILE LOOP..  How can a work around that?

Comment: Edit what is sensitive and post the code.

Comment: AND the webpage between the snippets is DYNAMICALLY generated.

Answer (score 0):

It IS....... it is impossible! Script runs without errors, so no, there is not a problem with the rest of the script (otherwise NONE of the website would function as it is the exact same coding). No examples exist of running ob_get_clean within a while loop, and for my purpose there is no alternative. Thanks Anyway! :)